# How can I find comments I made on a friend's post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

A friend of mine posts on Facebook multiple times a day every day. I made a comment and we had a conversation on one post a few months ago. I almost never comment or interact with this person.

How do I find the conversation we had? Is there a way to search for interactions between two people on one of their posts?

(I wish FB would allow you to just query their DB if its public info. At least query your own activity if nothing else.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the **Activity Log** feature of Facebook to search your comments.

1. Log in to https://facebook.com/.
2. Open your profile and from the top of the page (on top of your cover photo), click **View Activity Log**.
3. From the **Filters** menu, click **Comments**.
4. All your comments will begin loading. Use the **Activity Search** box to filter to comments between you and the other person.

Comment: Using the Activity Search box does not bring up any comments, merely my posts.

Comment: There does not appear to be an activity search box. What am I doing wrong? All I see are category and date filters.